# How do I get this plugin shortcode to display correctly

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to get a shortcode generated by a directory plugin to display correctly on a page but it just shows an error and text.

I've tried the shortcode on my custom theme and also a default wordpress theme but the same error occurs

This is the error I get.

Unknown column 'filter_display_name' in 'where clause' SQL: SELECT * FROM wpm2_drts_view_filter view_filter WHERE ( filter_bundle_name = 'experiences_dir_ltg' AND filter_display_name = 'default' )

Comment: As per the error getting is that "There is no column of filter_display_name in database table".

Comment: Can you share the name of the directory plugin and show the shortcode you are using please?

Comment: Hi, the plugin is Directories Pro and the shortcode is: [drts-directory-view directory="experiences"]

Comment: The shortcode for the search functionality works fine: [drts-directory-search directory="experiences"] But the view one doesn't

Comment: Hi Sohil, does that mean I have configured the plugin incorrectly in that the column is missing?

Comment: @TeddyG That is exactly what that means.  The column "filter_display_name" doesn't exist in the table.  If you look in the SQL statement at the very it is looking for a column filter_display_name with value of 'default'.  Maybe something happened during the install?

Comment: I decided the plugin install must be the problem so I uninstalled and started again. Everything seems to be working now so thanks everyone for the help.